# Installing and Running Windows VM in Virtualbox using CLI (Ubuntu Server)

Tags: server, virtualbox, windows-10

I want to setup a Windows VM in Ubuntuserver. I have the basics set up, but I don't know how to use VRDP to remote connect to run the windows 10 setup that is being loaded into the VM via an iso image of Windows. Can someone point me in the right connection as to how to setup a remote desktop connection so I can run the windows installation in the VM and then use it?
I have seen similar questions but none of them have the exact answer I am looking for unfortunately.

Comment: Just to add something further: I have to connect to the Ubuntu Server via ssh if it wasn't obvious from my post. Sorry, I can be a bit haphazard in describing things